# Does Gödel's incompleteness theorems imply there are infinitely many axioms in mathematics?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, axioms, foundations, incompleteness

I'm currently reading up on Gödel's incompleteness theorems for a thesis paper but I have trouble grasping the concept and significance of such theorems as it seems to be very abstract and non-intuitive. Is there anyone who could offer help to this newbie researcher on this matter as not even my professors could explain it well to me. Please help.

Comment: The short answer is, “No.” But I suspect this question is really displaying an underlying misconception.

Comment: You don't need Gödel's incompleteness theorem to realize that there are infinitely many axioms possible. If you don't provide more context, the question as stated is meaningless and I think we should close it.

Comment: I'm writing a paragraph on the implications of Godel's Incompleteness Theorems towards the Theory of Inventive Problem Solving (TRIZ), i.e. supposed to be a science of creativity proposed by Genrich Altshuller. I'm pondering the question whether there exits a problem that the TRIZ 40 principles can't solve. The past efforts by TRIZ practitioners to codify TRIZ as an exact science of creativity seems to parallel that of mathematicians where they intend to formalize all of Mathematics but crushed by Gödel's incompleteness theorems. I'm wondering whether the same applies to TRIZ.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: Rather than "infinitely many axioms", I suspect the OP may be asking about iterated Gödelian extensions of theories in the sense discussed in [*Transfinite progressions: a second look at completeness*](https://doi.org/10.2178/bsl/1102022662) by Torkel Franzén (2004) ([JSTOR archive](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3185190) and [another copy](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:983741/FULLTEXT01.pdf)). Incidentally, in this [31 May 2001 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/3rOWa0EdBcA/m/f-jiCPwFwzYJ) I made some comments **(continued)**

Comment: about Stephen Baxter's science fiction story "The Logic Pool", followed by mentioning Alex Kasman's (then) recently begun [Mathematical Fiction web pages](https://kasmana.people.cofc.edu/MATHFICT/all.php) (originally announced in this [31 January 2000 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/mFPAYeX3Ay4/m/SUaS7QfQVuYJ) to which [I gave some suggestions](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/mFPAYeX3Ay4/m/Zq8cYS-fjlMJ)). **(continued)**

Comment: Shortly after that 31 May 2001 sci.math post, Kasman contacted me (by email) for permission to use my comments about the Baxter story, and (this was probably in June 2001) I sent him a [revised worded version](https://kasmana.people.cofc.edu/MATHFICT/mfview.php?callnumber=mf206) to use.

Comment: It appears that the TRIZ principles are not formal mathematical axioms, so that whether a given problem can be solved by.them would seem to be to some degree a matter of debate, and far removed from the domain of what Goedel's incompleteness is about.

Comment: @Mark S.: I didn't look up [TRIZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIZ) until just now (right after I wrote those comments, and having quickly looked up the various URL's, I left for the gym), but now having done so it seems to me that it has a lot more relevance to things like Alfred Korzybski's [General Semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_semantics), Leibniz's [Characteristica Universalis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristica_universalis), and other [general systems theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_theory#General_systems_research_and_systems_inquiry).

Answer (score 3):

The broad answer is No.  However your question is based on a number of misunderstandings.  The first is that there isn't one single Formal Axiomatic System (FAS) that constitutes Mathematics.  Mathematics is a field and there are different FAS's within it.

There are FAS's that have a finite set of axioms.  There are limits to the expressive power of such systems but nothing prevents them from existing.